# Does the Terraform AWS provider data source aws_iam_role required argument "name" require the path to the role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

[Documentation for this data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_role)

Let's say I have two roles with the name `ssr-lambda` in two paths, `/path-a/`, and `/path-b/`

If we declare the data source as such:

```
data "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "ssr-lambda"
}
```

How would it know which role it is?

Do I need to include the path in the name of the role, like this: `/path-a/ssr-lambda` instead?

The documentation states that the `path` attribute can be referenced, but it's not an argument.

The `aws_iam_policy` data source does allow you to specify a path prefix, which is why I find this confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAM role names must be unique in each account, so my example is invalid, two roles would never have the same name.

I arrived at this conclusion by trying to create two roles in one Terraform project with the same name but different paths. It failed.

> Error: error creating IAM Role (ssr-lambda): EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name ssr-lambda already exists. status code: 409

Which is why the path is never needed when using a data source for them.

Comment: Note that IAM documentation explicitly states that same name CAN exist at different paths. What you observe here is a bug in AWS API.